# How to disable all animations in ios simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, core-animation

I have an ios application with a lot of animations and I need to debug it quickly. Is there a way to speed up or disable ALL animations in ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pause your running ios application in xcode
2. Insert into the console:

`p [(CALayer *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0] layer] setSpeed:100.f]`

3. You can change the speed appropriately.